# Cancellation of asylum in the USA and arrival on a visa

Tags: visas, usa, refugees

I was in the USA last year and applied for political asylum there. I was on the WaT program. Left before the end of the visa period, did not exceed the time of stay. When I left, I did not notify them that I was leaving and did not cancel the case review. I did it later, by mail. This year I applied for a visa again and it was pasted to me according to the same program. What are my chances of entering the USA at all?

Comment: What visa did you apply for this last time? And what do you mean by "it was pasted to me according to the same program"?